# Smoke detector with raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian

I want to create a smoke detector using raspberry pi, if anyone knows, please tell me the model of smoke detector that detects all kind of smokes e.g cooking, steam, cigarette, fire and is also be compatible with raspberry pi.

Comment: I would like to point out that steam does not fall under the category of smoke.

Comment: What exactly would this be used for? It may go without saying, but if this project would in any way monitor someone's safety, please take a large step back.

Comment: That being said... Shopping recommendations are specifically off topic here. If you have questions about interfacing with a specific model, or compatibility issues, feel free to ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 3):

"Smoke detectors" are actually gas sensors and they come in various flavours, but as far as I am aware there is not one ring to bind them all.  I think the kind commonly used in home alarms is an MQ2.  Carbon monoxide sensors are MQ7 based; you will find descriptions of other "MQ" sensors online.

However, they are analog devices, so you will need to use an [ADC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog-to-digital_converter) with the pi.